# How to convert psockaddr to sockaddr_in Lazarus?

Tags: network-programming, lazarus, winsock2

I,m creating a server/client chat application with winsock2 in lazarus.I have problem to obtain ip address from a connected user.My code looks like this :

```
uses winsock2,windows;
var
  wsa : twsadata;
  main_sock,client_sock : tsocket;
  server : sockaddr_in;
  client : psockaddr;
  c : integer;
begin
  wsastartup(makeword(2,2),wsa);
  main_sock := socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
  server.sin_family:=AF_INET;
  server.sin_addr.s_addr:=inet_addr('192.168.0.101');
  server.sin_port:=htons(8888);
  bind(main_sock,server,sizeof(server));
  listen(main_sock,3);
  while true do
  begin
    c:=sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    client_sock:=accept(main_sock,client,c);
    if (client_sock <> invalid_socket) then
    begin
      writeln('Connection accepted with these properties : ','??????');
      send(client_sock,'Hello',10,0); //just to make sure.
    end;
  end;
end.
```

I know the user ip address is stored in client(psockaddr) but i dont know how to take them out.I could do it if it was sockaddr_in structure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`psockaddr` is a pointer type, but `accept()` does not allocate memory, and your `client` variable is not pointing at anything. You need to change your `client` variable to `sockaddr_in` and pass it to `accept()` using the `@` operator.

```
var
  ...
  client : sockaddr_in;
  c : integer;
begin
  ...
  while true do
  begin
    c:=sizeof(client);
    client_sock:=accept(main_sock,psockaddr(@client),c);
    ...
  end;
end.
```